# Storing a file in pdf format in embedded system

Tags: c, file, pdf, embedded, storing-data

I am using Cortex-M3 controller LPC1788. I have implemented USB mass storage device on my controller and can read, write, delete, create files in *.txt format. I want to store a file in pdf format but dont know how to do it. i am using RTOS (not Linux).

I've been searching on web for *"storing pdf files in embedded systems"* but could not find much relevant data.

Please, help me.

Comment: Why do you want to use such a complex file format in an embedded system? If you really need formatting abilities, why not create an HTML or RTF file instead?

Comment: These files are client requirements which must me non-modifiable. Though read only files can be generated, by changing the attributes (properties) of file, but then too the file cant be modified. hence pdf

Comment: PDF files aren't non-modifyable. They are just slightly hard to modify. To make them really hard to modify, you'll also need to secure them.

Comment: Agreed. But thats not the point of discussion. The point is how do i actually implement it? Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) If you just want to store it, which means, you will never open it from the inside of the micro-controller: It will work just as another regular file, the file type is transparent to the micro-controller and file system, I see no point in your question.

2) If you want to decode the .pdf file inside the micro-controller: Don't do that, I doubt a MCU has power to do that, and I doubt you can find a pdf decoding algorithm that is OS independent and ANSI C.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? What's the point of having a PDF on the embedded system - are you going to try to view it on there?

Comment: No. viewing the pdf file on the microcontroller screen (7inch) is not my current requirement. But yes, in future the possibility of requirement is high.

@fanl I am using a RTOS. will it not be able to handle pdf? In case of no, i may have to migrate to other OS.
I am emphasising storing a file in PDF format on a USB drive, so that the user does not edit the file when viewing on computer.

I am open to implementing other file format that is uneditable

Comment: @D.7 I do not have further information on PDF decoding, you must know that it may be extremely cpu consuming and you may need a linux OS with a top end processor.

Comment: i am currently using LPC1788 which is a CortexM3 core, clocked at 120MHz, which has capability of reading a video file from SD card and display it on the 5' display. (Have example code and seen a video on the youtube also) Hence i am of the view (correct me) that the CPU is strong enough to handle pdf file system.